# ChilliSpot on OpenWRT

Tags: openwrt, hotspot

I'm trying to configure ChillySpot on OpenWRT and not sure what I'm doing wrong.
So far what I've done.

1. Added ChilliSpot via web menu to OpenWRT.
2. Added configuration to /etc/init.d/S45firewall from http://www.chillispot.org/chilliforum/topic18-documentation-howto-setting-up-openwrt-as-a-captive-portal-on-wrt54gl.html
3. Configured chilli.conf as per the page above.

There is a configuration mentioned in the manual, but I don't know where to put it to:

```
lan_ifname=br0
lan_ifnames="vlan0 eth1"
lan_proto=static
lan_ipaddr=192.168.1.1
lan_netmask=255.255.255.0
wan_ifname=vlan1
wan_proto=dhcp
```

Also, after restarting I don't see the chilli process running (via ps -w).

When I run `chilli -fd` manually, I don't see any connections when trying to connect to the WiFi router via the phone.

The router is TP-Link with OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment 12.09-rc1.
Internet is from external router via wireless connection.

Also, for some reason it says ipkg command doesn't exist so I cannot install anything via terminal.

And, if possible, please explain to me like I'm 5, I'm really new to networking configurations and especially routers.

The questions are:

- Where to put the mentioned configuration (`lan_iframe=....`)?
- What does it mean?
- Why isn't ChilliSpot running on router boot?

The chilli startup file is located in /etc/init.d and contains:

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
# Copyright (C) 2006-2012 OpenWrt.org

START=50

SERVICE_USE_PID=1
SERVICE_PID_FILE=/var/run/chilli.pid

start() {
    . /lib/functions/network.sh

    local ipaddr
    network_get_ipaddr ipaddr lan && \
            service_start /usr/sbin/chilli --dns1="$ipaddr"
}

stop() {
    service_stop /usr/sbin/chilli
}
```

The raidus daemon resides on a different machine and has been verified to work with radtest and other tools.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say much about Chillispot, but I can help you with some OpenWrt-specific things.

The post you linked is very dated (2007). Back then, OpenWRT used NVRAM system to store configuration. Now it uses UCI: http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci

To configure network settings, edit */etc/config/network* file.

ipkg command you are looking for is named **opkg**.

You might want to consider CoovaChilli instead of Chillispot and find a more recent manual. Maybe this one will help (didn't try it myself): http://opensource.telkomspeedy.com/wiki/index.php/OpenWRT:_Setup_Coova-Chilli

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using nodogsplash, it worked well for me when I needed to use a captive portal.

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/captive-portal/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.